# How to serve directories using Rack::Directory under Rails 3.2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack

I have a Rails application (version 3.2.3) that I'd like to serve some static files that are intentionally out of the public directory. This app is only a work in progress and I'm only using this to compare my responses as I'm progressing with the development.

I've set up the following mini Rack app that I'm autoloading with Rails:

```
APISchemaSampleServer = Proc.new do |env|
  Rack::Directory.new(Rails.root + "/spec/support/schema_definitions")
end
```

In my routes file I've mounted the small Rack application:

```
mount APISchemaSampleServer, at: '/samples'
```

My directory at `spec/support/schema_definitions` is an existing directory with a couple of files that I'd like to serve when I browse `/samples` within my Rails app.

When accessing the path above, however I am getting the following error:

```
NoMethodError

undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

I've been browsing the [Rack::Directory documentation](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/Rack/Directory.html) and tried a couple of different approaches, however this still does not seem to be working.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Found out what the problem was. I forgot to call the `Rack::Directory` component within `APISchemaSampleServer`. The right implementation looks something like this:

```
APISchemaSampleServer = Proc.new do |env|
  Rack::Directory.new('spec/support/schema_definitions').call(env)
end
```

(Note the extra `.call(env)` method.)

Also, the Rails.root prefix from the `Rack::Directory` constructor parameter can also be removed, given that `Rack::Directory` looks up the path from the current Rack application.

Comment: Very useful for showing some dev docs in a Rails app in `development` env. Thanks!